# How to use variable from script A in srcript B typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to get variable from other script to build the next part of the page on the basis of this data.

This is code to get data from API:

```
import Axios from "axios";
import React from "react";

export default class PersonList extends React.Component {
  state = {
    dataURL: [],    //from this variable I want get data
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    Axios.get(
      "https://g.tenor.com/v1/search?q=" +
        "mems" +
        "&key=" +
        "MY_TENOR_API_KEY" +
        "&limit=" +
        "1"
    ).then((res) => {
      this.state.dataURL = res.data;
      this.setState({ dataURL });
      console.log(this.state.dataURL);
    });
  }

  render() {
    return;
  }
}
```

Here I want to dynamically import the script and try to get access to variable from other script

```
import { useState } from "react";
import styles from "../styles/Form.module.scss";

function Form() {
  const [results, setResults] = useState();

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <div className={styles.form}>
        <input
          type="button"
          onClick={async (e) => {
            const { value } = e.currentTarget;

            const Fuse = (await import("../pages/api/tenor")).default;
            const fuse = new Fuse(state);    //I got there an error: "Cannot find name 'state'.ts(2304)"

            setResults(fuse.search(value));
          }}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Form;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, if you want to access a component's data from a different component you have a few options you can choose from.

1. Send that data as a prop.
   (only relevant if the 2nd component is a child/grand-child/etc.. of the 1st component)
2. Manage a "global state" (a single source containing the app's relevant data).
   This can be achieved via 3rd-party libraries ([Redux](https://react-redux.js.org/) / [MobX](https://mobx.js.org/README.html) / etc..)
   Or even via React's built-in [ContextAPI](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).
3. Use a shared hook containing the state which can then be accessed from other components.
   (only relevant for functional components)

IMO, the simplest option is the 3rd, but it will require turning `PersonList` into a functional hook.

An example should look like this:

```js
// Shared "PersonList" hook.

import Axios from "axios";
import React, { useState } from "react";

export function usePersonList() {
  const [dataURL, setDataURL] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get(
      "https://g.tenor.com/v1/search?q=" +
        "mems" +
        "&key=" +
        "MY_TENOR_API_KEY" +
        "&limit=" +
        "1"
    ).then(res => setDataURL(res.data));
  }, []);

  return dataURL;
}

// Form.tsx

import { useState } from "react";
import styles from "../styles/Form.module.scss";

function Form() {
  const [results, setResults] = useState();
  const dataURL = usePersonList();

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <div className={styles.form}>
        <input
          type="button"
          onClick={async (e) => {
            const { value } = e.currentTarget;

            const Fuse = (await import("../pages/api/tenor")).default;
            const fuse = new Fuse(dataURL);

            setResults(fuse.search(value));
          }}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Form;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try [React Redux](https://react-redux.js.org/) or [useReducer](https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_usereducer.asp) to share variable between components.